# How do I assign a null value to a variable in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, scripting, null

I want to assign a null value to a variable called `$dec`, but it gives me errors. Here is my code:

```
import-module activedirectory
$domain = "domain.example.com"
$dec = null
Get-ADComputer -Filter {Description -eq $dec}
```

Comment: The value is `$null`. `null` is, as you found, an error.

Comment: That's because it should be `$null`. I can't believe the most basic of searches wouldn't have thrown that at you

Comment: I tried that also @arco444 with no success.

Comment: What are the errors, if using `$null`?

Comment: @arco444 my search brought me here.

Answer (score 63):

These are automatic variables, like `$null`, `$true`, `$false` etc.

`about_Automatic_Variables`, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> **$NULL**
>   `$null` is an automatic variable that contains a **NULL** or empty
>   value. You can use this variable to represent an absent or undefined
>   value in commands and scripts.
>
> Windows PowerShell treats `$null` as an object with a value, that is, as
>   an explicit placeholder, so you can use $null to represent an empty
>   value in a series of values.
>
> For example, when `$null` is included in a collection, it is counted as
>   one of the objects.
>
> ```
> C:\PS> $a = ".dir", $null, ".pdf"
> C:\PS> $a.count
> 3
> ```
>
> If you pipe the `$null` variable to the `ForEach-Object` cmdlet, it
>   generates a value for `$null`, just as it does for the other objects.
>
> ```
> PS C:\ps-test> ".dir", $null, ".pdf" | Foreach {"Hello"}
> Hello
> Hello
> Hello
> ```
>
> As a result, you cannot use `$null` to mean "no parameter value." A
>   parameter value of `$null` overrides the default parameter value.
>
> However, because Windows PowerShell treats the `$null` variable as a
>   placeholder, you can use it scripts like the following one, which
>   would not work if `$null` were ignored.
>
> ```
> $calendar = @($null, $null, “Meeting”, $null, $null, “Team Lunch”, $null)
> $days = Sunday","Monday","Tuesday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"
> $currentDay = 0
>
> foreach($day in $calendar)
> {
>     if($day –ne $null)
>     {
>         "Appointment on $($days[$currentDay]): $day"
>     }
>
>     $currentDay++
> }
> ```
>
> output:
>
> ```
> Appointment on Tuesday: Meeting
> Appointment on Friday: Team lunch
> ```

Answer (score 7):

Use `$dec  = $null`

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-6#null):

> $null is an automatic variable that contains a NULL or empty value. You can use this variable to represent an absent or undefined value in commands and scripts.
>
> PowerShell treats $null as an object with a value, that is, as an explicit placeholder, so you can use $null to represent an empty value in a series of values.

Answer (score 3):

If the goal simply is to list all computer objects with an empty description attribute try this

```
import-module activedirectory  
$domain = "domain.example.com" 
Get-ADComputer -Filter '*' -Properties Description | where { $_.Description -eq $null }
```

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, use `$null`.

However, the handling of `$null` is not so simple.

In *lists* (or, more precisely, `System.Array` objects) `$null` is treated as a placeholding object *when indexing the list*, so `($null, $null).count` outputs `2`.
But otherwise `$null` is treated as a flag signifying that there is no content (no object;  or, more precisely, a "null-valued expression", as reported by `.GetType()`), so `($null).count` outputs `0`.
Thus

```
$null.count;  # Output = 0
($null).count;  # Output = 0
(, $null).count;  # Output = 1
($null, $null).count;  # Output = 2
($null, $null, $null).count;  # Output = 3
```

Note:  the same output is returned from `.count` and `.length` in the above context.

Similarly if explicitly assigning any of the above to a variable, as in

```
$aaa = $null;  $aaa.count
$bbb = ($null, $null);  $bbb.count
```

which output, respectively, `0` and `2`.

Similarly if looping with `ForEach`, as in

```
$aaa = $null;  ForEach ($a in $aaa) {write-host "Foo" -NoNewLine}
$bbb = ($null, $null);  ForEach ($b in $bbb) {write-host "Bar" -NoNewLine}
```

which output, respectively, *nothing* and `BarBar`.

However, note well that *when operating on an individual item that has been returned from a list* `$null` is again treated as a "null-valued expression", as can be confirmed by running

```
$xxx = ($null, "foo", $null);  ForEach ($x in $xxx) {write-host "C=" $x.count "| " -NoNewLine}
```

which outputs `C= 0 | C= 1 | C= 0 |` .