# No email addresses in outlook ContactItem via powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook

When I examine a `ContactItem`, all of the Email#Address values are null. I have tried settings the value then printing the value. The change is reflected in Outlook, however, no value can be retrieved via PowerShell.

Below are some snippets:

```
$Outlook=NEW-OBJECT –comobject Outlook.Application
$Contacts=$Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(10).items
$Contactsfolders = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(10).Folders
$testFolder = $Contactsfolders | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq 'Test Folder'}
$testContact = $testFolder.Items(1)

echo $testContact
$testContact.Email1Address = "BobDoe3@doe.com"
echo $testContact
```

Here is the output of the above execution. Note I've removed some of the uninteresting information to shorten.

**First Echo**

```
Application                  : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class                        : 40
Session                      : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.NameSpaceClass
ConversationTopic            : John Doe
FormDescription              : System.__ComObject
GetInspector                 : System.__ComObject
Importance                   : 1
LastModificationTime         : 10/31/2017 5:57:04 PM
MAPIOBJECT                   : System.__ComObject
MessageClass                 : IPM.Contact
OutlookInternalVersion       : 154971
OutlookVersion               : 15.0
Saved                        : True
Sensitivity                  : 0
Size                         : 11614
Subject                      : Bob Doe
UserProperties               : System.__ComObject
Account                      : 
Anniversary                  : 1/1/4501 12:00:00 AM
AssistantName                : 
AssistantTelephoneNumber     : 
Birthday                     : 1/1/4501 12:00:00 AM
CompanyAndFullName           : The Doe Company
                               Doe, Bob
CompanyLastFirstNoSpace      : 
CompanyLastFirstSpaceOnly    : 
CompanyMainTelephoneNumber   : 
CompanyName                  : The Doe Company
ComputerNetworkName          : 
CustomerID                   : 
Department                   : 
Email1Address                : 
Email1AddressType            : 
Email1DisplayName            : 
Email1EntryID                : 
Email2Address                : 
Email2AddressType            : 
Email2DisplayName            : 
Email2EntryID                : 
Email3Address                : 
Email3AddressType            : 
Email3DisplayName            : 
Email3EntryID                : 
FileAs                       : Doe, Bob
FirstName                    : Bob
FTPSite                      : 
FullName                     : Bob Doe
FullNameAndCompany           : Doe, Bob
                               The Doe Company
Gender                       : 0
GovernmentIDNumber           : 
Hobby                        : 
Home2TelephoneNumber         : 
HomeAddress                  : 
HomeAddressCity              : 
HomeAddressCountry           : 
HomeAddressPostalCode        : 
HomeAddressPostOfficeBox     : 
HomeAddressState             : 
HomeAddressStreet            : 
HomeFaxNumber                : 
HomeTelephoneNumber          : 
Initials                     : B.D.
InternetFreeBusyAddress      : 
ISDNNumber                   : 
JobTitle                     : 
Journal                      : False
Language                     : 
LastFirstAndSuffix           : 
LastFirstNoSpace             : 
LastFirstNoSpaceCompany      : 
LastFirstSpaceOnly           : 
LastFirstSpaceOnlyCompany    : 
LastName                     : Doe
LastNameAndFirstName         : Doe, Bob
```

**Second Echo**

```
Application                  : Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ApplicationClass
Class                        : 40
Session                      : System.__ComObject
Subject                      : Bob Doe
UnRead                       : False
UserProperties               : System.__ComObject
Account                      : 
Anniversary                  : 1/1/4501 12:00:00 AM
AssistantName                : 
AssistantTelephoneNumber     : 
Birthday                     : 1/1/4501 12:00:00 AM
Business2TelephoneNumber     : 
BusinessAddress              : 
BusinessAddressCity          : 
BusinessAddressCountry       : 
BusinessAddressPostalCode    : 
BusinessAddressPostOfficeBox : 
BusinessAddressState         : 
BusinessAddressStreet        : 
BusinessFaxNumber            : 
BusinessHomePage             : 
BusinessTelephoneNumber      : 
CallbackTelephoneNumber      : 
CarTelephoneNumber           : 
Children                     : 
CompanyAndFullName           : The Doe Company
                               Doe, Bob
CompanyLastFirstNoSpace      : 
CompanyLastFirstSpaceOnly    : 
CompanyMainTelephoneNumber   : 
CompanyName                  : The Doe Company
ComputerNetworkName          : 
CustomerID                   : 
Department                   : 
Email1Address                : 
Email1AddressType            : 
Email1DisplayName            : 
Email1EntryID                : 
Email2Address                : 
Email2AddressType            : 
Email2DisplayName            : 
Email2EntryID                : 
Email3Address                : 
Email3AddressType            : 
Email3DisplayName            : 
Email3EntryID                : 
FileAs                       : Doe, Bob
FirstName                    : Bob
FTPSite                      : 
FullName                     : Bob Doe
FullNameAndCompany           : Doe, Bob
                               The Doe Company
Gender                       : 0
GovernmentIDNumber           : 
Hobby                        : 
Home2TelephoneNumber         : 
HomeAddress                  : 
HomeAddressCity              : 
HomeAddressCountry           : 
HomeAddressPostalCode        : 
HomeAddressPostOfficeBox     : 
HomeAddressState             : 
HomeAddressStreet            : 
HomeFaxNumber                : 
HomeTelephoneNumber          : 
Initials                     : B.D.
InternetFreeBusyAddress      : 
ISDNNumber                   : 
JobTitle                     : 
Journal                      : False
Language                     : 
LastFirstAndSuffix           : 
LastFirstNoSpace             : 
LastFirstNoSpaceCompany      : 
LastFirstSpaceOnly           : 
LastFirstSpaceOnlyCompany    : 
LastName                     : Doe
LastNameAndFirstName         : Doe, Bob
```

Something interesting that I've found while playing with different results and solutions.
I've found that both of the below queries results in the same matches which confuses me as I would have thought `myString -ne ''` is checking if the string is not empty. It appears that `myString -ne ''` and `[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($myString)` can both return true which seems impossible, but I think there are some cases where this could happen. Also note that `IsNullOrEmpty` function is extraordinarily faster.

```
$Listconstact=$session.GetDefaultFolder(10).Folders | %{$session.GetFolderFromID($_.EntryID).Items | where Email1Address -NE ''}
```

and

```
$Listconstact=$session.GetDefaultFolder(10).Folders | %{$session.GetFolderFromID($_.EntryID).Items | where {[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Email1Address)}}
```

Results from tukan's answer:

```
VERBOSE: From:
VERBOSE: Subject: How are things
VERBOSE: From:
VERBOSE: Subject: See you soon
VERBOSE: From:
VERBOSE: Subject: Meeting Times
```

Comment: Check the `IMAddress` property.  I've seen that if an organization is Skype for Business enabled, you may find the actual e-mail listed under that property instead.

Comment: Probably duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11326062/getting-the-internet-e-mail-address-from-an-exchange-outlook-contact-programmati

Comment: @FoxDeploy in fact we are using Skype for Business.  I will check this out.  I looked over all the parameters as they were printed but found no email address value from a general echo.  I appreciate the suggestion however.

Comment: @galford13x, did you look at the link  I posted, does it help?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: Indeed I did, much appreciated.  I will try that as well.  It appears FoxDeploy's suggestion isn't the answer.

Comment: @FoxDeploy: I've looked at the IMAddress and it appears to be blank as well.

Comment: What powershell version and which outlook do you use ?

Comment: @tukan: I'm using powershell v5.1.14393.1715 and outlook 2013 (v15)

Comment: @galford13x: I have taken a shot to solve your issue, but I'm unsure if that is what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try Something like this:

```
$Outlook=NEW-OBJECT –comobject Outlook.Application
$session=$Outlook.session
$Listconstact=$session.GetDefaultFolder(10).Folders | %{$session.GetFolderFromID($_.EntryID).Items | where Email1Address -ne ''}

#only one item
Write-Host "First element mail : $($Listconstact[0].Email1Address)`n`n" 


#All mails
Write-Host "All element mail :"
$Listconstact.Email1Address
```

Comment: This did not seem to work.  However, I added a #Listconstact.Count to see how many items matched the LINQ statement, and it was 1222.  This makes me think there are values, however, they are not being printed.  Here is the output: 1222\n
First element mail :   \n


All element mail :\n

Comment: try this and look file $Listconstact.Email1Address | out-file "c:\temp\result.txt"

Comment: The result.txt file is blank.  Also note, that I did the following if( $Listconstact[0].Email1Address -ne '' ) results in true and $Listconstact[0].Email1Address.Length results in 0.  However, interestingly enough [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Listconstact[0].Email1Address) results in true also which makes me question the original Where-Object query.

Comment: and if you try to modify where Email1Address -ne $null

Comment: That results in an empty Enumerable (no matches).  From my playing, it appears that [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($Listconstact[0].Email1Address) == ($Listconstact[0].Email1Address -ne '') which seems impossible.  I'm sure there is some strange powershell pitfall here which has turned into a rabbit that've I've followed.  I'm not entirely sure where to go at this point.

Answer (score 0):

I'm kind of fuzzy on what you are tying to achieve.  To me it seems you are mixing two things together - contacts & folders.

I'm not sure if you are trying to get information from Outlook emails or Address book (since you are using folder I guess it is the first).  I'll gladly rectify the solution if it is not solving your issue.

**Note:** I don't have identical configuration but close enough: Outlook version: *15.0.0.4420* and PowerShell version: *4.0.30319*.

I'll try my best to cover what I think you are trying to solve in my eyes - *Getting all contacts' email addresses (adding also subject) from received emails in "Test Folder" @Outlook*.

```
# Making sure we have the assembly loaded
Add-Type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" 
# saving the mapping
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlDefaultFolders" -as [type]

# new object
$Outlook=NEW-OBJECT –comobject Outlook.Application
# setting the correct namespace
$namespace = $Outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI")

# getting all folders in Outlook inbox
$inbox = $namespace.GetDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInbox)
# filtering out all but the "Test Folder"
$targetFolder = $inbox.Folders.Item("Test Folder")

# iteration on email message 
ForEach($emailMessage in $targetFolder.items) {
    # getting all the information from the message 
    Write-Verbose -message "From: $($emailMessage.GetProperty) $($emailMessage.SenderEmailAddress)" -Verbose
    Write-Verbose -message "Subject: $($emailMessage.Subject)" -Verbose
}
```

Why *MAPI* namespace?  Well because the [MSDN says so](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook._application.getnamespace.aspx).

> I would have thought myString -ne '' is checking if the string is not
>   empty.

Yes it does do that. The difference is that the method `[String]::IsNullOrEmpty($myString)` is checking for Null **OR** Empty in a string.  In case, when you have a `$null` value then you can have both true.  It is not empty and is $null. (for more see what does it mean to have a [$null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697349/how-to-assign-a-null-value-to-a-variable-in-powershell) value)

Comment: I haven't checked back in a while, I'm sorry.  tukan, what you have does sort of work, however, I was looking in the Address book.  However, your solution does have the same problem.  My ouput does not contain a From: email address.  The Subject does print correctly however.  The From: ..... output is blank.

Comment: Are you using Exchange or Exchange Online? If you are you can use the EWS API instead of the (slow) COM way which also requores Outlook. EWS should always be the preffered way to retrieve information like this from an Exchange server. If you're not using Exchange I've said nothing of course.

Comment: @galford13x that is weird.  I have tested it on my Outlook and works correctly.  Do you have Office365 or something like that?

Comment: Indeed I believe it is Office365.

Comment: @galford13x I see.  That is probable cause of the issue.  You have to approach it differently then.  I do not have any Office365 to test so I can't help you there.

Comment: I understand, I appreciate the help anyway.  I believe it may be the way our AD is setup.  If I do figure something out I'll be sure to post the solution.